# Am building an App using Angular 2 and backend as Shopify Api, While calling Shopify API using Angular 2 am getting issue CORS-ORIGIN error

Tags: shopify, angular2-services

Look at the API i used

https://{{apikey}}:{{password}}@{{yourstore}}.myshopify.com/admin/products.json

while calling the Shopify API in Post Man it's working, data is getting from Shopify Store

Problem is that While calling API in Angular 2 only getting the issue "CORS-ORIGIN"

Answer (score 0):

You should not make front-end calls to the API as that exposes your **private** API Key to the world. You can re-think your pattern of use here with a read up on using API **App Proxy** calls. You can thn safely make XHR calls using the App Proxy to call the API and return results. No more CORS problems and security!